# On which stage (lexical analysis, syntax analysys, and so on) is most of the compilation time spent?

Tags: compilers

I know that during compilation we need to undergo several stages like lexical analysis, syntax analysis and so on. Which of them takes the most time?

Comment: The answer could in principle depend on the compiler.

Comment: Also very much depends on the language. Swift type deduction can be pretty hard, and I heard that some popular language has features that are NP-complete at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

For a few compilers I've seen compilation times was reduced 3+ fold when optimization was disabled, so otherwise they spent most time on optimization passes.

Comment: I remember one compiler where optimisation was limited by available memory, so if you increased RAM, then more optimisations were possible, so more time was spent.